# making second api call after getting data from the first api

Tags: javascript, reactjs, api

I have this first API call which gets me some data and once I have got the data from this api , only then I need to make the second api call . It must happen in the series and not parallelly. How can we do this in react ComponentDidMount?
I am listening to firebase .
Let us suppose that the first api gets me a matchId and now we need to use this matchid to make second call just after first api call without any click .

Let us suppose that this is my first firebase call .

```
const cardsListener = 
        getDATA()
        .onSnapshot( (doc)=>{
            console.log("doc is ",doc);
            let data = doc.data();
            console.log("data",data);
            this.setState({
                 datainstate:data
            });
        });
```

Answer (score 2):

Thanks to `async/await`, you can wait until an action is done.

```
componentDidMount() {
  this.firstApiCall()    
}

async firstApiCall() {
  await fetch("http://myurl.com", {
     method: 'POST',
     body: JSON.stringify(data), // data can be `string` or {object}!
     headers:{
       'Content-Type': 'application/json'
     }
   })
   .then(res => res.json())
   .then((responseJson) => {
     //if it worked
     this.secondApiCall()
   })
   .catch(error => console.error('Error:', error))
}

secondApiCall() {

}
```

Comment: Well ,i am listening from firebase and not the https .

Answer (score 0):

There are many ways you could do this. My preferred way is to use async await. I'll give an example of how you would use this below.

```
        const getData = async() => {
          try {
            const apiCall1 = await axios.get(SOME_URL);
            const apiCall2 = await axios.get(SOME_URL/apiCall1.data.id)
            return apiCall2
          } catch(e) {
            return e
          }
        }
```

It's a silly example but you hopefully get the point. I make my first API call and await the response. Then I make my second API call using some data from the first call then return. You can do whatever logic you want in-between that.

You could also use a callback or promise but I think async await is clearer, and generally less code.

Async Await Documentation - https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/async_function
Promises Documentation - https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise
Callback Documentation - https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Callback_function

Answer (score 0):

You can follow something like this:

```
componentDidMount() {
  fetch("apiUrl").then(res => {
    //Do whatever you want to do with the response or get the id
    const {id} = res;
    fetch(`apiUrl/${id}`).then(response => {
      // Do anything with the response of the api call here
    }).catch(error => {
      //Thing to do on error
    });
  }).catch(err => {
    //Thing to do on error of 1st api call
  });
}
```